# UITableView goes under translucent Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationbar

I am trying to have a transparent navigation bar in IOS 7 app. There is a full screen image in my application. I am also having a UITableView over that image. When I use the code below, image fits the screen as I want but UITableView goes under navigation bar.

in `viewDidLoad`

i use

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
self.navigationController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

it is being ok when I change to `self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;` but then I lose transparency at navigation bar.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You could set the contentInsets of your tableView so it is initially below the navigation bar, but would scroll behind it (content would be overlapping)

```
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(44,0,0,0);
```

Or you could offset the frame of the tableview. Then the scrolling content would be cut off below the navigation bar (which wouldn't look good, too)

Comment: this is helpful when first viewdidload but when I press table cell and go next view then come back to this view, tableview goes down again more then it supposed to. I mean it goes 88 px down..

Comment: That shouldn't happen. Are you adjusting anything in viewWill(Did)Appear that could cause that behaviour? If not, I suppose you used the frame solution and for some reason the contentInsets are set correctly the second time. So it could help to overwrite them again to be UIEdgeInsetsZero.

Comment: I am setting only your setting in viewDidLoad. I haven't implemented any other appear or load methods.My next view is opaque one not translucent. When I go to it and come back, viewDidLoad and your code is not called but still it is going down then normal.

Comment: Try logging the contentInsets and frame in viewDidAppear to find out what's happening there. Then you should get more insight on what needs to be adjusted.

Comment: yes it work but it is like animation. first i see wrong one after it triggers viewDidAppear it moves true location.

Comment: Then use viewWillAppear to adjust things before the view is visible.

Comment: It's not advisable to hard code 44 here, as Apple can (and has) messed with their internal heights and values in the past.  Additionally, the nav bar height for landscape is different than portrait so rotation will look wrong.  Recommend using @Bill Chan's answer below http://stackoverflow.com/a/27770486/285694

Comment: Remember the status bar is 20 pixels tall so the inset might need to be 64 to start below both of those

Comment: This won't work properly in both the portrait and landscape mode and should have never been accepted as the answer.

Comment: be sure to set the scrollIndicatorInsets too!

Answer (score 49):

I my case helped this one (modified version of Bill Chan's code):

**Objective C version:**

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];   
    CGRect rect = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame;
    float y = rect.size.height + rect.origin.y;
    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(y, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

The point is that table have to be pushed down for the height of navigationBar (`rect.size.height`) plus status bar height (`rect.origin.y`);

**Swift version (also compatible with Swift 2):**

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    if let rect = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame {
        let y = rect.size.height + rect.origin.y
        self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake( y, 0, 0, 0)
    }
}
```

Comment: I just implemented a very same solution. See my answer

Comment: y should be defined with "let" since it won't be mutated

Comment: you should also considering adding self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(y, 0, 0, 0) to make sur the scroll won't be shown under the nav bar

Answer (score 35):

I had the similar problem for iOS 9. When I first open viewController, tableView is under top bar. Then after scrolling tableView everything works fine.

1. Select your view controller
2. Click the 'Attributes Inspector' tab
3. Uncheck 'Under Top Bars'

[image]

Comment: I have added [self.view setNeedsLayout]; [self.view layoutIfNeeded]; in viewWillAppear() and disbale as above. This worked for me.

Comment: I have done same thing that you did but for me it's not working any other solution if you have then please tell me because I already spend hours on it. Thank You

Comment: you save my day )

Comment: This is what I wanted. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

Set the y-position of tableview to height of the navigation bar plus height of the status bar (let it be `height`)

i.e,

```
  height = 64; // height of navigation bar = 44(In portait), height of status bar = 20
  tableView.frame = CGRectMake(tableView.frame.origin.x, height , tableView.frame.size.width, tableView.frame.size.height);
```

If you are using autolayout just change the update the tableView top constraint instead of changing frame.

and also change viewController automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets to NO

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets =  NO;
```

If you are supporting different orientation update frame and contentInset to (52) because navigation bar height in landscape mode is 32.

check this [Sample](https://github.com/yathishbl60/NavigationBarClearColor)

Comment: I do this but when I present the ViewController from another view. The navbar flashes to white. Screenshot: http://j.airkrft.com/XBOA

Comment: @JordanBrown I didn't get the screenshot , Link is invlaid.

Answer (score 7):

This is working in both landscape mode and portrait mode in iOS8:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
  [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

  CGRect rect = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame;

  float y = -rect.origin.y;

  self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(y ,0,0,0);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Better not to hardcode the Inset values as it might based on the orientation of the device.

**Code:**

```
func setTableViewContentInset() {

    let contentInsetHeight = topLayoutGuide.length
    let contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(contentInsetHeight, 0, 0, 0)

    tableView.contentInset = contentInset
    tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInset
}

func scrollToTop() {

    if tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows?.count > 0 {

        let topIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)

        tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(topIndexPath, atScrollPosition: .Top, animated: false)
    }
}

func scrollToTopOfVisibleCells() {

    if let visibleIndexPaths = tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows where tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows?.count > 0 {

        let topMostVisibleIndexPath = visibleIndexPaths[0]

        tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(topMostVisibleIndexPath, atScrollPosition: .Top, animated: false)

    }        
}

//MARK: Load Views
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setTableViewContentInset()
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    scrollToTop()
}

//MARK: Trait collection change
override func traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
    super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)

    setTableViewContentInset()
    scrollToTopOfVisibleCells()
}
```

Comment: Upvoted because you the only answer that mentions the scrollIndicatorInsets, which are a must

Answer (score 5):

Solutions that introduce a magic constant don't scale most of the time. For example, if the next iPhone introduces a different navigation bar height we'll have to update our code.

Fortunately, Apple provided us cleaner ways of overcoming this issue, for example [topLayoutGuide](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621367-toplayoutguide):

> The topLayoutGuide property comes into play when a view controller is
> frontmost onscreen. It indicates the highest vertical extent for
> content that you don't want to appear behind a translucent or
> transparent UIKit bar (such as a status or navigation bar)

Programmatically you can achieve with the following code snippet (the same can be achieved via IB too):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

  automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
  tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
  NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
    tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
    tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: 
       topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
    tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
  ])
}
```

**Note:** topLayoutGuide is deprecated in iOS 11, we should use the [safeAreaLayoutGuide](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/2891102-safearealayoutguide) property of UIView instead.

Answer (score 3):

## Introduction

I am new to both iOS development and Stack Overflow, so forgive me if my post isn't perfect.
I also had this issue, and when I used the content insets for my UITableView it worked perfectly upon loading first, or when visiting it from my other tabs; however, if I navigated back to the view, it would have the extra "padding". I figured out a work around, so that my UITableView will be correctly placed every time.

## The Issue

When you first load the UITableView, or tab to it, it needs the insets to correctly start the table below the navigation bar, but when you navigate back it does not need the insets, because for some reason, it correctly calculates for the placement of the UITableView. This is why you can get the extra padding.

## The Solution

The solution involves using a boolean to determine whether you have navigated away, so that it can correctly determine whether it needs the content insets or not.
In `-(void)viewDidLoad` I set `hasNavigatedFurther = NO`. Then:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    if (!hasNavigatedFurther) {
        self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(64, 0, 0, 0);
    } else {
        self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
        //In order to allow visiting between tabs and retaining desired look
        hasNavigatedFurther = NO;
    }
}
```

In order to make this work, you need to set `hasNavigatedFurther = YES` just before your code that pushes another view onto the navigation stack.

```
-(void)btnTouched:(id)sender {
    hasNavigatedFurther = YES;
    NextViewController* nvc = [NextViewController new];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:nvc animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: You can use this solution instead of what you have introduced, In your viewDidLoad add: ```edgesForExtendedLayout = [.bottom, .left, .right]```

Answer (score 1):

I came up with the following solution, which, on navigating to the view controller for the first time, adjusts the table view's `contentInset` for the navigation bar's height, taking into account any padding that the top cell might have. When returning to this view controller after pushing another view controller onto the stack, I then re-adjust the `contentInset` to `UIEdgeInsetsZero`:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self adjustEdgeInsetsForTableView];
}

- (void)adjustEdgeInsetsForTableView {
    if(self.isMovingToParentViewController) {
        self.tableViewForm.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height + padding, 0, 0, 0);
    } else {
        self.tableViewForm.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I combined @Adam Farrell and @Tash Pemhiwa 's solutions, and finally the code below works for me:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self adjustEdgeInsetsForTableView];
}



- (void)adjustEdgeInsetsForTableView
{
    if(self.isMovingToParentViewController) {
        self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
    } else {
        self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(64, 0, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Hope this will help people who waste couple of hours on this weird UI behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Constrain the table view to the bottom of the navigation bar. The table view will automatically be offset by 44, but then in code we can just do this:

```
tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: -44, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

The bar is transparent and has no color, but the table view does not overlap it at all. Notice the word "Hook" gets cut off despite the navigation bar being transparent. This will only work of you constrain the table view top edge to be 0 from the navigation bar. NOT 0 from the top view.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

All you need is <s>love</s> this:

```
assert(tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior == .automatic)
```

there is zero need to do ugly magic constants beardance from iOS 11 onwards

I did not even need to set contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior to .none
to fix navbar underlapping.

```
.automatic
```

worked automagically

Comment: according to the documentation `automatic` _is_ the default value.

Answer (score 0):

try to use layoutguide to fix

```
var constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint]()   
let guide = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
            constraints.append(self.tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.leadingAnchor))
            constraints.append(self.tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.trailingAnchor))
            constraints.append(self.tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.topAnchor))
            constraints.append(self.tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.bottomAnchor))
```