# Swift Tableview header on to of screen

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I have setup a tableview in my VC with a custom header. I also have a Navigation bar which I have make it transparent. I want the tableview header to be on the top of the screen, not below the navigation bar. I have tried to put -navigationBar.height in the CGRect y origin of the headerViewFrame but seems not working.

I have:[image]

And I want something like: [image]

Here is some code :

```
func setupTableView() {
    let tableView = UITableView()
    tableView.frame = view.bounds
    tableView.backgroundColor = .blue
    view.addSubview(tableView)
    tableView.separatorStyle = .none
    tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView
}

lazy var headerView: LFHeaderView = {
    let headerView = LFHeaderView()
    headerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: SCREENW, height: 242)
    return headerView
}()
```

Thank you

Comment: this could be an escamotage: hide the navigation bar in the navigation controller. Make a button equals to the back button, with a pop action. You will have the same result you are looking for.

Comment: yeah it was my idea too but as a new swift developer, I doesn't know if by doing that, I would lose the features given by the navigation controller

Comment: nope you won't. I'm doing that in an app. Where the designers completely removed the navigation bar, but still I needed the functionality of the navigation controller.

Comment: You have top constraint to safe area or superview?

Comment: @AdrianBobrowski ty for your comment and you are right. I'll use it for iPhone X compatibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try inseting the UITableView

```
[self.tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(44,0,0,0)];
```

Alternatively in swift

```
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(44, 0, 0, 0)
```

Comment: that line solve the problem 
     `if let navBarH = navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height {
            tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-navBarH, 0, 0, 0)
       }` Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Change your **frame** of headerView like

```
headerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: min(0, self.tableView.contentOffset.y), width: SCREENW, height: 242)
```

If Still facing issue then another option is go to

> Main.StoryBoard -> Select Your VC -> Attribute Inspector -> Do Check Under Top Bar.

[Look this answer, Here you need to do/apply check mark.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24468831/uitableview-goes-under-translucent-navigation-bar#42901379)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use UITableViewController and use:

```
tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?
```