# Set Navbar Translucent To Start animation in UITableViews

Tags: ios, swift

I am facing an strange issue with navigation bar. I have an app with UItableViewControllers & UIViewController inside UINavigationController.

App works fine but when set navigation bar style to Translucent, tableview scroll up automatically in view controllers.

I have try to reset my content inset for table as below

```
self.cardTableView.contentInset = .zero
```

but is does not work. I also tried below links

[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24468831/uitableview-goes-under-translucent-navigation-bar) [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24468831/uitableview-goes-under-translucent-navigation-bar/27770486) [Link3](https://github.com/samvermette/SVPullToRefresh/issues/181) [Link4](http://blog.motioninmotion.tv/fixing-the-ios-7-navigation-bar-overlap-problem/)

But does not work.

Please let me know how to resolve this issue. Any idea would be grateful.

I am working with Xcode 9.1.

Comment: Which language would like the answer for?? Because you have tagged both objective C and swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your view controller, try the following snippet:

**iOS < 11**

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
```

**iOS == 11**

```
self.cardTableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentBehavior.never
```